# Can I use 'better beauty'?

Tags: collocation

By 'better beauty' I mean sth like cruelty free beauty, 'way to a better beauty'. I want to use it in the name for some kind of blog. English is my second language, but I don't know whether it sounds ok for native speakers. Maybe 'way better than beauty' sounds better..?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Yes, it sounds OK.  However, this blog may not be the only [better beauty](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22better%20beauty%22).

Comment: Do you mean "a better way to beauty"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native speaker, I would say Yes. *A better beauty* sounds fine to me in this context and would mean "a better kind of beauty".